# Can i call another function inside the GetElement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call another function inside the getElement but it is not working everything when i change my selection. When i select Car, in the textbox my varxumb should populate. Any idea...

```
document.getElementById("mycall1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><select id = "forcx" onchange="fillgap()"><option>Select</option><option>Force</option><option>Angle</option><option>Area</option></select></td>';
function fillgap() {
    var xnumb = 20;
    var forcxlist = document.getElementById("forcx");
    if (forcxlist == "Force") {
        document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;
    }
}
```

Comment: A Dom element can not equal a string. You should be listening for a change event on a select element.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and include HTML as well, please.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how this "Force" value is coming to check. 
you can try these solutions.

```
if (forcxlist == "Force")
```

instead use

```
var forcxlistText = forcxlist.options[forcxlist.selectedIndex].text;
if (forcxlistText == "Force")
```

or use value technique

```
<div id ="mycall1">
</div>
<div id ="result1">
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("mycall1").innerHTML = '<td><select id = "forcx" onchange="fillgap(this.value)"><option value="1">Select</option><option value="2">Force</option><option value="3">Angle</option><option value="4">Area</option></select></td>';

    function fillgap(value){
         var xnumb = 20;         
         if (value == "2"){
             document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = xnumb;    
         }
    }
</script>
```

or use

```
<div id ="mycall1">
</div>
<input type="text" id="result1" value=""/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("mycall1").innerHTML = '<td><select id = "forcx"><option value="1">Select</option><option value="2">Force</option><option value="3">Angle</option><option value="4">Area</option></select></td>';

    document.getElementById("forcx").onchange = function (){
        var xnumb = 20; 
        var forcxlist = document.getElementById("forcx");
        var forcxlistValue = forcxlist.options[forcxlist.selectedIndex].value;
        if (forcxlistValue == "2"){
            document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;    
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually force coming from the selection i fixed my question check my option list and it is not wokring

Comment: sarje i used the value technique but it doesn't work function fillgap(value){
     var xnumb = 20;         
     if (value == (1)){
         document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;    
     }
}

Comment: and i changed option and added value .... like this document.getElementById("mycall1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><select id = "forcx" onchange="fillgap(this.value)"><option>Select</option><option value = '1'>Force</option><option value = '2'>Angle</option><option value = '3'>Area</option></select></td>';

Comment: Ok, first tell me this td tag is getting added to html body or not and if getting added then tell me the function fillgap() getting accessed or not?

Comment: that value technique provided by which is not adding td tag to html before it was and fillgap() function wasn't working now both not working

Comment: if fillgap() still not accessible then you have to add script tag dynamically and need to add this function in it.

Comment: you mean option vlaue = '1' this is working...huh interesting cause it is not and what you mean by add script tag

Comment: see above added code copy past and see by urself. If not working then add first solution that I have provided by adding 2 lines in ur code.

Comment: i added  <div id ="mycall1">
</div>
<div id ="result1">
</div> under the body and still doesn't work

Comment: use value="1" instead value='1'

Comment: oh ok what is this line means var forcxlist = document.getElementById("forcx");
        var forcxlistValue = forcxlist.options[forcxlist.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: I was missing this line do i need to add this

Comment: yes, you need to add it. that line is taking value of selected text. like for Force it is taking 2 as value.

Comment: i added the line and still it doesn't work. i have to try different method

Answer (score 0):

The forcxlist variable is an element object, returned by the document.getElementById method. Afterwards, you are checking if this element object is equal to "Force", which is a string (meaning the contents of your if block will never be executed). Did you mean to check if the *contents* of that object are equal to Force?

Instead of

```
 if (forcxlist == "Force"){
```

use

```
if (forcxlist.innerHTML == "Force"){
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can't use innerHTML so i changed it to .value

```
document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here.

First, you are expecting `forcxlist` to be a string, not an element, so you need to use `.value` to get the selected value of the dropdown.
Second, you should do your comparison with `===` not `==`, as this ensures type equality as well, and is best practice.

I would also recommend building your `select` using HTML elements. It keeps things cleaner, is more readable, and is easier to maintain.

Since you are using the same `id` for the `select`, you would have to  change the selector in your `fillgap` handler to `var forcxlist = e.target.value;`, this way the event will fire based on only the `select` that you are interacting with, regardless of how many rows you have in the table.

Updated code is below, and an updated working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vno8hgpy/2/). As per your comment about adding additional rows, the fiddle has this working as well.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addDropDown()">
<table id="mycall1"></table>

<script>
  function addDropDown() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("mycall1");
    var newRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell.appendChild(createDropDown("forcx", fillgap));
  }

  function createDropDown(id, onchange) {
    var dd = document.createElement('select');
    dd.id = id;
    dd.onchange = onchange;
    createOption("Select", dd);
    createOption("Force", dd);
    createOption("Angle", dd);
    createOption("Area", dd);
    return dd;
  }

  function createOption(text, dropdown) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = text;
    dropdown.add(opt);
  }

  function fillgap() {
    var xnumb = 20;
    var forcxlist = e.target.value;

    if (forcxlist === "Force") {
        document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;
    }
  }
</script>

<input type="text" id="result1">
```

Comment: any idea when i am entering second row how come this method doesn' work

Comment: I updated my answer with new code, and an updated fiddle that demonstrates this using HTML elements, as opposed to using `innerHTML` and strings. Hopefully this works for you.